# MySQL Date_Format based on today's date and another column?

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I am aware of the MySQL Date_Format function but am looking to achieve the following:

I have on column with a day date in 2 digit format (01-30). I am trying to update another date formatted field with the current year, the next month (m+1) and the day field mentioned previously.

In PHP i would do this using mktime function but this must be done using mysql calls only.

Is it possible to transform in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set field1 = concat(date_format(curdate(),"%Y-%m"),'-',field2) + interval 1 month
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called STR_TO_DATE in mysql which you should be able to use to create a brand new date with using the seperate parts you described in your problem. The final input into the function should be STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y') where argument one is the actual date string and argument two represents the format of the new date. You should be able to create the first argument by concatenating your parts together and then specifying whatever date format you need.